# Excel IF .10 Then True Else False

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel formula but it is always returning False:

A1 Cell has the value 10%:

```
=IF(A1="10%","TRUE","FALSE")
```

I also tried the following:

```
=IF(A1=".10","TRUE","FALSE")
```

Comment: what if you remove the speech marks from your second example?

Comment: Remove the quotes from the number.  Also it is going to return false as 35% <> .10

Comment: surely it needs to be if A1 > 10%? else like @ScottCraner says, its always gonna return false

Comment: @John on a side note, `=IF(<condition>,TRUE,FALSE)` can be simplified to just `=<condition>`. However, in your case, the `TRUE` and `FALSE` are actually in quotes, which means this formula is returning a *string* rather than the *Boolean value*. This may be what you want, but I just thought I would point this out because I've never seen anyone desire that a formula returns a Boolean value as a string.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I do it sometimes because my Excel is in spanish, so the booleans appear in spanish. I need them in english when I export to Access or SQL.

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera Ahh, ok. This explains why that was probably done in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=IF(A1=0.1,"TRUE","FALSE")`

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
=A1=.1
```

Assuming your A1 cell is Number format and `.` for decimal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on if you want to treat A1 as a string or as a percentage.

1. A1 is a string:

To ensure "35%" is a string, you can type the following in A1:

```
'35%
```

The single quote converts it to a string. Your formula should now work.

2. A1 is a percentage

You need to modify your formula like this, since 10% is really 10/100=0.1:

```
=IF(A1=10/100,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value of your percentage is a floating-point number, you should consider that the rounding errors may affect your equality evaluation.

It may be safer to check if the two numbers (the value in the cell `A1` and the percentage 10%) are *almost* equal (e.g. up to 5 digits):

```
=IF(ROUND(ABS(A1-0.1),5),"TRUE","FALSE")
```